# Split dataframe data into different worksheets in excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        
for i,key in enumerate(c):    
    df_new.get_group('Isci Code').to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index=False)
writer.save()
print("Done")
```

I want to group my dataframe data in  'df_new' based on the data in column named 'ISCI Code' and publish it into separate worksheets of the same excel called 'output.xlsx' but I am getting error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_group'".

Any recommendations?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- you can use `df.groupby` function to get the groups of that particular columns and iterate over it and dump it into sheets. Here `key` is grouping key(which is used to group the data) and g is dataframe which contains data of that particular group

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        
for key,g in df_new.groupby('Isci Code'):    
    g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index=False)
writer.save()
print("Done")
```